# Update data locally while using background sync service wroker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I want to make something just like the twitter pwa app. How can I implement the background sync like twitter in which if we retweet it will automatically show up in the tweet section of profile while we are offline. I am using react with workbox for the background sync and able to send the queue for the background sync. But unable to change the data locally because I am using wrokbox for the data and which donot change until we are online again.

I want to add the discussion answer while offline and show immediately while we are offline even after a reload until we are further online and also sync when we are back online. How can I get there. Any Idea.

Comment: Only way I find out is to use the idb and implement the add update and background sync also by our self . Any Other ideas.